# Как передать стрим через веб-сервер, не загружая в память?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть необходимость передать поток данных с одного сервера на другой.
Напрямую они общаться не могут, вынужден перегонять данные через третий.

В качестве минимально воспроизводимого создал сервер

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
      var stream = new FileStream(@"LoadTest.zip", FileMode.Open);
      return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public async Task Post()
    {
      using (var file = new FileStream("ResultLoadTest.zip", FileMode.Create))
        await this.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(file);
    }
```

и клиент

```
      var httpClient = new HttpClient();
      var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:59846/api/values",
         HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, CancellationToken.None);
      var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

      var request = new HttpRequestMessage
      {
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:59846/api/values"),
        Content = new StreamContent(stream),
      };
      var send = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, CancellationToken.None);
      send.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Проблема:
при размере файла в 400мб клиент занимает памяти на 800мб. Хочется перегонять буквально по сети, не загружая никакую память.

Comment: А реверс-прокси на каком-нибудь nginx в качестве промежуточного звена не пойдет?

Comment: @rdorn серверы между собой в любом случае не умеют общаться, а там ещё различная аутентификация, доп параметры, про которые один о другом не знает, хватает мелочей, которые не дают сделать это легко и просто. Думал о реверс-прокси, но пока кажется не особо реализуемо.

Comment: А если вместо HttpClient использовать старый низкоуровневый WebRequest? Он вроде с буфером фиксированного размера и читает, и пишет. HttpClient, как я понял, кэширует файл целиком,а поток там для красоты интерфейса.

Comment: @rdorn а как это правильно сделать? если я пытаюсь в запрос записать стрим, то снова память растёт сильно `await stream.CopyToAsync(await request.GetRequestStreamAsync());`

Comment: @Vasek честно не понял как им пользоваться, простой вариант который я накидал требует даже больше памяти - до 1гб. Что-то вида `await inputStream.CopyToAsync(stream); stream.Close();`

Comment: Я попробовал ваш код(убрал только HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead из SendAsync) на Asp net core и все прекрасно работает. Хост локальный. Памяти больше 15 мб не сьел.

Comment: @Vasek в качестве сервера у меня тоже aspnetcore. А вот клиентом обычный консольный проект выступает с net46, и именно он потребляет много памяти.

Comment: В консоли на net46 добавате `request.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true;` На NetCore это делается автоматом.

Comment: @Vasek оформляйте ответом, как минимум на вопрос оно отвечает гарантированно. Свой боевой кейс буду уже отдельно проверять и подгонять под условия.

Comment: @Vasek если сами не планируете оформлять, не против, если я оформлю? Чтобы вопрос не висел без ответа.

Comment: Я не против.///

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для передачи потоковых данных по TCP применяется [Chunked transfer encoding](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

Включить его можно добавив в `Headers` запроса соответствующий признак:

```
  var request = new HttpRequestMessage
  {
    ...
    Headers = { TransferEncodingChunked = true },
  };
```

Итоговое потребление памяти практически на нуле, чего и требовалось достичь.